# Why $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I just need clarification about answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4580323/lim-n-to-infty-frac1-sqrtnk-1-frac1-sqrt2-frac1-sq/4580406#4580406) question:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}}{\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}}{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}} = 2$$
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\right)^k = 2^k$$

---

In this case I don't understand why
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$
My reasoning. $$\frac{ \frac{1}{a} }{b - c} = \frac{1}{a(b-c)}$$Hence, we get:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1 - \sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \frac{1}{n} }{ \frac{n}{n} + \frac{1}{n} + \sqrt{\frac{n^2}{n^2}+\frac{n}{n^2} } } = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{0}{1+0+\sqrt{1+0}}=0$$
While $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ \sqrt{\frac{n}{n} + \frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{\frac{n}{n}} }{ \sqrt{\frac{n}{n} + \frac{1}{n} } } = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{1+0} + \sqrt{1} }{\sqrt{1+0}} = 2$

Any explanation, what's going on? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\cdot  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}\right)$$

To rationalize the denominator $\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n$, we need to use the conjugate based on the formula: $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, which gives

$$\left(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}\right)\cdot \left(\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}\right)=n+1-n=1.$$

Hence, we have

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=1+1=2.\end{align}
$$

Comment: +1 for your solution @Sebastiano

Comment: (+1). I made a small edit, you can always consider rollback.

Comment: @lonestudent ahahaha don't worry I am scarse in English language :-(.

Comment: Me too..  The edit is too small anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Let $s = \sqrt{n+1}$ and $t = \sqrt{n}.$ Then:

$$\mathcal{L} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{s}}{s-t}  = \\
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\displaystyle\frac{1}{(s-t)}\frac{1}{s} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\displaystyle\frac{s+t}{(s-t)(s+t)}\frac{1}{s}.$$

But:

$$(s-t)(s+t) = s^2 -t^2 = (n+1) - n = 1,$$

and hence:

$$\mathcal{L} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s+t}{1}\frac{1}{s} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{s+t}{s}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}.$$

Comment: +1 for your solution.

Answer (score 4):

This equality is purely algebraic. Forget about the limits.
$$\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}}\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}.$$The numerator equals $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ and the denominator equals $\sqrt{n+1}^2-\sqrt n^2=n+1-n=1.$

Your mistake is in "$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1-\sqrt n\sqrt{n+1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1n}{\frac nn+\frac1n+\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{n^2}+\frac n{n^2}}}$" (the minus sign in the denominator has become a plus sign).

Comment: +1 for your solution.